# Migration in live server

Tags: magento2, database, installation, web-services

here I am again seeking for help. I've been stuck for 2 days working about this. when I'm working on localhost my website is working.

Well, after migration from localhost to my web server it gives me this kind of look:

[image]

All my work and products are gone.

What I just see is this mess can anyone help me to solve this problem please.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different options to fix this (I believe after migration you have ran setup:upgrade and indexer already.)

First Try:
Login to admin panel, Go to catalog category and save category.

if saving category doesn't fix this issue then try below :

Login to admin panel, Go to catalog Products and manually save product

Answer (score 0):

First Please apply below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

then delete `cache`, `page_cache` and `generation` folders from `var` folder

and check is that working ?

if not then check **is your database correctly imported.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem i just modified the following

```
/app/design/frontend/Sm/revo/Sm_ImageSlider/templates/default.phtml
/app/code/Sm/Deals/Helper/Data.php
/app/code/Sm/ListingTabs/Helper/Data.php
/app/design/frontend/Sm/revo/Sm_Categories/layout/categories_index_index.xml
/app/design/frontend/Sm/revo/Sm_MegaMenu/layout/megamenu_index_index.xml
```

thanks for the help and suggestions

Comment: as this is your answer please select it as the answer